# Read.csv is treating T as True and F as False, even if I am using stringsAsFactors=FALSE

Tags: r

The following piece of code is treating T as `True` and F as `False`, even if I am using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`:

```
raw_time_series_df <- read.csv(input_file_names[i], header=FALSE,
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
```

Comment: You can use the `colClasses` argument to specify the types of each column. That way, you'd be able to tell R that you want a character column during the read.

Comment: @lmo, post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `colClasses` argument to specify the types of each column. That way, you'd be able to tell R that you want a character column during the read.

for example,

```
raw_time_series_df <- read.csv(input_file_names[i], header=FALSE, as.is=TRUE,
                               strip.white=TRUE, colClasses="character")
```

Will return a data.frame where all variables are of type "character." You can specify column types individually by feeding `colClasses` a vector of types. From the help file, `?read.table`, colClasses is

> A vector of classes to be assumed for the columns. Recycled as necessary. If named and shorter than required, names are matched to the column names with unspecified values are taken to be NA.
>
> Possible values are NA (the default, when type.convert is used), "NULL" (when the column is skipped), one of the atomic vector classes (logical, integer, numeric, complex, character, raw), or "factor", "Date" or "POSIXct".

Note that "NULL" can be used to skip a column.